# Custom Category attribute created but not saved

Tags: attributes, category-attribute

I've created a custom extension in order to add a custom attribute on product Categories.
Here's the code I've used to create it:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'label'=> 'Featured Author',
    'input' => 'checkbox',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => 0,
    'source' => "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean",
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'featured_author', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

The attribute is created and it's visible on backend. I also checked eav_attribute database table and the attribute is created in there too.

But changing the attribute's value (check/uncheck) and then saving category has no effect at all. The attribute value is not updated/saved. The checkbox is always unchecked.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: But is there a value in the db for your attribute in `catalog_category_entity_int`? As a general advice. Try to avoid checkboxes and radio buttons in the backend forms. They don't play well with Magento. Use instead a yes/no attribute and have a dropdown. The problem with checkboxes is that the value is not sent when the checkbox is unchecked. With selects you will have the value 0.

Comment: Marius  i am agree with you.i am suggesting...
ktsixit to   use yes no attribute..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the field yes/no  instead of checkbox

```
    $installer =new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup;
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
    $attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
    $attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'featured_author',  array(
        'type'     => 'int',
        'label'    => 'Featured Author',
        'input'    => 'select',
        'source'   => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'required' => false,
        'default'  => 0
'group' => "General Information"
    ));

    $installer->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId,
        $attributeSetId,
        $attributeGroupId,
        'featured_author',
        '10'
    );

    $attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'featured_author');

    $installer->run("
    INSERT INTO `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity_int')}`
    (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`)
        SELECT '{$entityTypeId}', '{$attributeId}', `entity_id`, '1'
            FROM `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity')}`;
    ");

    $installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have already inserted the code you suggested but the selectbox appears emply, without any option available. How can I populate the selectbox with options line "Yes" and "No"?

Comment: I changed some attribute values directly in database, and it worked. But do you know why when changing the code has no impact on attribute? I re-indexed website and cleared cache. Is there something else I should have done to apply changes?

Comment: i need check .see that later

Answer (score 2):

I have checked a very simple solution to add new attribute in category form in Magento admin.

I found 3 tables are responsible for that.

**Step 1**:- Create an attribute from your admin panel.

**Step 2**:- Go to database and open `eav_attribute` table, find the attribute with `attribute_code`. Now make `entity_type_id` 4 to 3

**Step 3**:- Go to `eav_entity_attribute` table insert a row `entity_type_id =3`
, `attribute_set_id = 3`, `attribute_group_id=4`, `attribute_id = your attribute id`.

**Step 4**:- Now go to the `catalog_eav_attribute` table put `is_global = 1`, 
    `is_visible=1`.

Now refresh your category edit page it will come